# Polymorphic function over types combined by typeclass

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeclass

Consider such domain logic: three types of users: Civilians, ServiceMembers and Veterans. Each of them has 'name', stored in different attributes.

Task is to write a function, accepting each of the types and returning 'C' char for Civilians, 'V' char for Veterans and 'S' char for ServiceMembers.

I have such record declarations:

```
data ServiceMemberInfo = ServiceMemberInfo { smname::String }
data VeteranInfo = VeteranInfo { vname::String }
data CivilianInfo = CivilianInfo { cname::String }
```

My first idea was to combine them by such typeclass:

```
class UserLetter a where
  userLetter :: a -> Char
```

And implement instances:

```
instance UserLetter ServiceMemberInfo where
  userLetter _ = 'S'

instance UserLetter VeteranInfo where
  userLetter _ = 'V'

instance UserLetter CivilianInfo where
  userLetter _ = 'C'
```

In this case, `userLetter` is a function I wanted.
But I really would like to write something like that (without typeclasses)

```
userLetter1 :: UserLetter a => a -> Char
userLetter1 (CivilianInfo _) = 'C'
userLetter1 (ServiceMemberInfo _) = 'S'
userLetter1 (VeteranInfo _) = 'V'
```

which throws compilation error: 'a' is a rigid type variable bound by

Another way is to use ADT:

```
data UserInfo = ServiceMemberInfo { smname::String }
              | VeteranInfo { vname::String }
              | CivilianInfo { cname::String }
```

Then userLetter1 declaration becomes obvious:

```
userLetter1 :: UserInfo -> Char
userLetter1 (CivilianInfo _) = 'C'
userLetter1 (ServiceMemberInfo _) = 'S'
userLetter1 (VeteranInfo _) = 'V'
```

But, lets say, I don't have control over ServiceMemberInfo (and others) declarations. How userLetter1 can be defined?

Is there a way to declare one ADT with existing ServiceMemberInfo (and others) types?

Comment: No other sane way but those two, as far as I can see.

Comment: `class UserLetter` is the preferable solution, because it is extendible. Suppose later you get type `OfficerInfo`; all you need to do is add the instance of the class. It is also least useful...because if you have entirely unrelated types, how can you use them together? For instance, how are you going to store a mixed list of all civilians, service members and veterans? You will need a boxed type, like @leftaroundabout suggested below, and then you can as well use pattern matching on the boxed type.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use existing type-classes to do this, and meet the pattern-matching-like syntax requirements you have, by defining a *type*-level function which returns the appropriate string, then picking the term-level string that corresponds to the type-level one. Here's a complete working example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy

data ServiceMemberInfo = ServiceMemberInfo { smname::String }
data       VeteranInfo =       VeteranInfo {  vname::String }
data      CivilianInfo =      CivilianInfo {  cname::String }

type family Label x :: Symbol
type instance Label ServiceMemberInfo = "S"
type instance Label       VeteranInfo = "V"
type instance Label      CivilianInfo = "C"

label :: forall a. KnownSymbol (Label a) => a -> String
label x = symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy (Label a))
```

We can see it go in ghci:

```
*Main> label (ServiceMemberInfo "")
"S"
```

However, there's a lot not to like about this solution: it requires many extensions; it's complicated (hence will be a maintenance problem); and it is in some sense done this way *only* to paper over a design problem in the underlying types, which would be better served by eliminating the technical debt you've incurred already.

Answer (score 1):

I would just redefine the datatypes like so:

```
newtype UserInfo = User { type :: UserType, name :: String } 
data UserType = Civilian | ServiceMember | Veteran
```

But if you really can't change the original datatypes, then you can do something like the following with `ViewPattern` and optiononally `PatternSynonyms`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms, ViewPatterns, StandaloneDeriving, DeriveDataTypeable #-} 

import Data.Typeable 

data ServiceMemberInfo = ServiceMemberInfo { smname::String }
data VeteranInfo = VeteranInfo { vname::String }
data CivilianInfo = CivilianInfo { cname::String }

deriving instance Typeable ServiceMemberInfo
deriving instance Typeable VeteranInfo
deriving instance Typeable CivilianInfo

pattern ServiceMemberInfo_ x <- (cast -> Just (ServiceMemberInfo x))
pattern VeteranInfo_ x <- (cast -> Just (VeteranInfo x))
pattern CivilianInfo_ x <- (cast -> Just (CivilianInfo x))

type UserLetter = Typeable 

-- without pattern synonyms
userLetter :: UserLetter a => a -> Char
userLetter (cast -> Just (CivilianInfo{})) = 'C'
userLetter (cast -> Just (ServiceMemberInfo{})) = 'S'
userLetter (cast -> Just (VeteranInfo{})) = 'V'
userLetter _ = error "userLetter"

-- with pattern synonyms
userLetter1 :: UserLetter a => a -> Char
userLetter1 (CivilianInfo_ _) = 'C'
userLetter1 (ServiceMemberInfo_ _) = 'S'
userLetter1 (VeteranInfo_ _) = 'V'
userLetter1 _ = error "userLetter"
```

This isn't very safe because you can call `userLetter` with *any* `Typeable` (which is everything); it could be better (but more work) to define a class like:

```
class Typeable a => UserLetter a 
instance UserLetter ServiceMemberInfo 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> “Is there a way to declare one ADT with existing ServiceMemberInfo (and others) types?”

Why, sure there is!

```
data UserInfo = ServiceMemberUserInfo ServiceMemberInfo
              | VeteranUserInfo VeteranInfo
              | CivilianUserInfo CivilianInfo
```

Then `userLetter1 :: UserInfo -> Char` can be defined as before, but you still keep the seperate record definitions of `ServiceMemberInfo`, `VeteranInfo` and `CivilianInfo`.

Instead of declaring this as a new named ADT, you can also make it an “anonymous variant type”:

```
type (+) = Either

type UserInfo = ServiceMemberInfo + VeteranInfo + CivilianInfo
```

Then you can define

```
userLetter1 :: UserInfo -> Char
userLetter1 (Left (Left _)) = 'C'
userLetter1 (Left (Right _)) = 'S'
userLetter1 (Right _) = 'V'
```

Clearly, this is not really preferrable: the anonymous constructors are much less descriptive.

Comment: But then I'd need to wrap my VeteranInfo instances to be VeteranUserInfo...  Any easy (generalized) way to do so?

Comment: @AlexanderShestakov: yeah (see edit), but it's a bad idea. Having new constructors to explicitly distinguish the types is _a good thing_, because it makes the code clear and gives the compiler plenty of hints for type checking. That is of course provided these type are _supposed_ to be rigorously distinguished. Frankly, it quite looks to like you shouldn't have three different types at all, but just use a simple variant label in a single `UserVar` type (as user2407038 suggests in the beginning).